# import csv file in SAS virtual machine

Tags: sas, virtual-machine

I new in SAS and I have big data around 3000 rows and 10 columns in CSV file and I want to import this to SAS but I have MAC and I use SAS in virtual machine how can I import it?
I try to copy it but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3000 rows isn't big!  I can't comment on the specifics of your VM and file access configuration, but one easy way is to simply copy paste your CSV values into SAS Studio and read them in using the [datalines](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000188182.htm) statement, eg:

```
/* set up a temp fileref to hold your csv */
filename tmp temp;

/* read in the raw data using datalines, and write to fileref */
data _null_;
infile datalines ; 
file tmp ;
input; 
put _infile_;
datalines;    
col1,col2,col3,col4                  
your,data,goes,here
see,how,it,works?
;
run;

/* import the csv any way you like */
proc import datafile=tmp out=work.want dbms=csv replace; 
  getnames=yes; 
run;
```

A more efficient option would be to build the dataset direct from the datalines - I'll leave it to you to decide which is more convenient, but here's a head start:

```
data work.want;
infile datalines delimiter=','; 
input col1 $ col2 $ col3 $ col4 $;
datalines;                      
your,data,goes,here
see,how,it,works?
;
run;
```